# Why am I being told this typecast is redundant?

Tags: c#, resharper

The equation is pretty simple, `int = int * int / int`;  However, the multiplication of the ints could get too big, I'm trying to cast everything up to `Int64`s before doing it and then cast the result back down to an int.  Thus I have:

```
int = (int)((Int64)int * (Int64)int / (Int64)int);
```

and it's complaining about all three of the Int64 casts.

**Note**:  the target is x86 as I'm using a 32-bit only library.  *The machine itself is 64-bit*.  I could understand it with x64 target.

- Am I missing something?
- Does Resharper not understand the problem of intermediate values overflowing?

Comment: What if you only cast one of them? It could be that one cast is sufficient, and each cast makes the other two casts redundant.

Comment: With that many points to your name, it would have been nice if you'd have at least considered using code tags to improve the readability of your question.

Comment: Could you add those *compiler complains*  ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just stay with long for your result?

Comment: @MauriceReeves:  The result is certainly within the range of an int.  #2/#3 should normally be no greater than 1 and since it's describing a physical reality it's constrained by sanity.

Comment: @aLearner:  It was one line, no formatting to be broken.  I don't see that the code tag improves the readability.

Comment: @LorenPechtel readability, as the name implies, is for your _readers_. Snippets of code are probably best enclosed using code tags - that's why they're provided.

Comment: @aLearner: When there are multiple lines of code the CODE tags certainly help.  I just don't see any benefit with only one line.

Comment: @LorenPechtel So, why do you think your question was edited to include the code tags by more than one person? Also feel free to share your thoughts here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160322/correct-usage-of-code-tags

Comment: @aLearner: Obviously others disagree with me on the merits of code tags here.  I'm just saying I omitted them because I didn't see the value in this case rather than not knowing or being lazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Int16 a = 1000;
Int16 b = 40;

var c = a * b; // c is Int32 because compiler does not want overflow

// The cast makes a3 Int64
// No need to cast a1 because all operations involving Int64
// will be Int64 to ensure no overflows when arithmetic operations are performed
var a3 = a1 * (Int64)a2;
```

Same for :

```
var a3 = (Int64)a1 * a2;
```

**Resharper is a smart as you know, it gives the warning for all the 3 casts in your code because any 1 of them makes same sense.**

Edit:
One more thing, all the operations on the right are evaluated and output is Int64 after the 1 cast done. The final int cast will work on the finally calculated value and it is explicit cast to int as Int64 cannot be directly cast to int (preventing overflow). There are no intermediate value overflows.

Comment: Your answer describes it the best.  I would have realized what was up if it had only flagged #2 and #3 but I guess it's taking a local view and not seeing the fact that doing everything it suggested would be bad.

Comment: Yes, but before you would have realized, resharper realized which is the one of them that you want to cast, so it showed redundant for all of them :)

Answer (score 3):

The very first cast produces an Int64. Int64 * int is Int64. Divided by int is Int64.

Answer (score 0):

casting one of them is enough

```
int x, y, z, w;
x = y = z = int.MaxValue;
```

look at the behavior below and you'll understand it all

```
textBox1.Text = ((Int64)x * y).ToString();
```

output:  4611686014132420609

```
textBox2.Text = (x * y).ToString();
```

output:  1

```
textBox3.Text = ((int)((Int64)x * (Int64)y / (Int64)z)).ToString();
```

output: 2147483647